# Exception thrown using superclass reference can still be caught in the catch block using subclass reference?

Tags: java, exception

```
class ExceptionA extends RuntimeException {}
class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA {}
class ExceptionC extends RuntimeException {}

class statCheck {
    void method1() {
        ExceptionA ex = new ExceptionB();
        try {
            int i = 1; throw ex;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("2");
            throw e;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("1");
        }
    }

    void method2() {
        try {
            method1(); 
            System.out.println("4");;
        } catch (ExceptionB e) {
            System.out.println("5");
            throw new ExceptionC();
        }
    }

    void method3(){
        try {
            method2(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("6");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new statCheck().method3();
        System.out.println("7");
    }
}
```

I am running this java code and the output received is :

```
2
1
5
6
7
```

But why is that the case? Why 5 is being printed? Shouldn't the answer be just :

```
2
1
6
7
```

The catch block which displays 5 on the console is catching the exception of type `ExceptionB` but the exception thrown is of type `Exception`. Is it possible to catch the superclass reference with some subclass reference? Or it works because the superclass reference is in turn pointing to the same subclass reference? Can someone please clear the air on this?

Thanks

Comment: "the exception thrown is of type Exception" - no, the only exceptions actually created are of type `ExceptionB` and `ExceptionC`. The type of the variable you're using is mostly irrelevant - the execution-time type of the exception thrown in `method1` is `ExceptionB`.

Comment: (As an aside, this example is *much* more complicated than it needs to be - you really only need a single derived exception type, and a single method called from main...)

Comment: @JonSkeet is the type of variable we are using really irrelevant? Because `method2` will still catch this exception if I catch it using `ExceptionA`

Comment: I think you don't understand subclassing, An ExceptionB **is** an ExceptionA just as it **is** an Exception.  If that were not so, then subclassing would be pointless.

Comment: Yes. Change it to `RuntimeException ex = new ExceptionB();` and you'll see the same behaviour. The type there is *only* relevant in terms of whether the compiler allows you to throw the exception - in this case you can do so with no `throws` clause because the compiler knows it's an unchecked exception.

Comment: @ArfurNarf but my question is if a subclass reference `ExceptionB`, in this case, can hold the reference of type `Exception` in `method2`?

Comment: are you asking (in last comment) something like `ExceptionB x = new Exception()`  or, if you prefer,  `try { throw new Exception(); } catch {ExceptionB x) { ... }`?

Comment: @user16320675 The try catch case

Comment: @AashishAggarwal - the object that is thrown in your method1 is an ExceptionB.  That you briefly held a reference to it in variables typed as ExceptionA and Exception does not change that the object is actually an ExceptionB. It remains an ExceptionB when it arrives at the catching code in method2.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of java is dynamically linked. As in, which method is invoked / which catch block is chosen is all decided only on the spot depending on the actual type of the object. What you use in the code (as in, the type of your variable) is irrelevant. When you write:

```
Exception a = new SomeSpecificException();
```

You have 2 separate things here: You have an object, and a reference. It's like `new SomeSpecificException` pops a treasure chest in existence and buries it somewhere in the beach. And `Exception a;` is a treasure map. The `=` sign means: Draw a map to this treasure on this treasure map. This leads to proper explanations of how java works, if you then write `Exception b = a;` you have 2 treasure maps, both going to the same treasure, for example. The fact that your `b` variable is of type `Exception` is not saying much; that merely means the treasure map has, on top of it, a statement: "This map is either blank (`null`), or, is guaranteed to lead to real treasure! In addition, that treasure will definitely be some sort of exception!"

Almost everything in java doesn't care about that header on your treasure map, it cares about the treasure.

The only exception to that rule is method resolution. Given:

```
void foo(Number n) { System.out.println("Number!"); }
void foo(Integer n) { System.out.println("Integer!"); }

Number x = 5; // integer
foo(n); // prints Number!
```

And that's because method names include their parameter types (so, our two `foo` methods here are as unrelated as a method named `joe` and `jane` would be - different names, effectively), and resolving which method is intended is a compile-time/static thing, i.e., based on the heading on your treasure maps and not based on treasure because that's not info available at compile time.

Contrast to:

```
class Parent {
  void foo(Number n) { System.out.println("Parent!"); }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  void foo(Number n) { System.out.println("Child!"); }
}

Parent p = new Child();
p.foo(5); // prints Child!
```

Here the resolution (which actual code ends up being executed at runtime) is dynamic: It cares about the treasure (which is `new Child()`), not about the heading on your treasure map (which is `Parent p`).

`catch` blocks **are like the latter** - they are resolved **at runtime**, based on **the type of the object** (and not of the treasure map).

This:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("2");
            throw e;
```

Still throws an object of type `ExceptionB`. It doesn't magically change object types. That thinking doesn't make sense at all. Imagine such an operation changes the type of an object, that would imply you could have objects whose type is some abstract type, which is obviouslly impossible, 'abstract' means 'cannot be instantiated', and therefore, **no** objects can possibly exist whose type is an abstract type. But they could, of course, be of some *subtype* of an abstract type which is fine. Given:

```
AbstractList x = new ArrayList();
```

`x` is a variable (treasure map), pointing at an object (treasure). The map promises that, whatever you find, it's some sort of AbstractList. All of which is fine - none of this makes the treasure *itself* an AbstractList. It's an ArrayList. It will remain an ArrayList regardless of what maps you care to draw (= variables you care to set) that lead to it.